# Configure Log4net to write Different Output files

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, log4net

I am new to Log4net. I successfully implement the library in my application, now I want to create different files based on Log type.

like for Debug I want to create DebugLog.txt

similarly

InfoLog.txt for Info Log

WarningLog.txt for Warn Log

ErrorLog.txt for Error Log

I am working on MVC C#

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Looks to be a repeat of this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4862868/configuring-log4net-to-write-to-different-files-based-on-log-level?rq=1

Comment: in above link it says that it is not possible but I have seen it

Comment: You can use the same technique as outlined in this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/42116509/1395758

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example from another article - I don't know if this is what you are looking for:

```
<log4net>
<appender type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender" name="classApp1">
  <file value="c:\\Library1.txt" />
  <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
    <conversionpattern value="%d [%t] %-5p %c - %m%n" />
  </layout>
</appender>

<appender type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender" name="classApp2">
  <file value="c:\\Library2.txt" />
  <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
    <conversionpattern value="%d [%t] %-5p %c - %m%n" />
  </layout>
</appender>

<appender type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender" name="application">
  <file value="c:\\Application.txt" />
  <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
    <conversionpattern value="%d [%t] %-5p %c - %m%n" />
  </layout>
</appender>

<logger name="ClassLibrary1">
  <level value="ERROR" />
  <maximumfilesize value="256KB" />
  <param value="ERROR" name="Threshold" />

  <appender-ref ref="classApp1" />
</logger>

<logger name="ClassLibrary2">
  <level value="WARN" />
  <maximumfilesize value="256KB" />
  <param value="WARN" name="Threshold" />

  <appender-ref ref="classApp2" />
</logger>

<logger name="WindowsApplication1">
  <level value="WARN" />
  <maximumfilesize value="256KB" />
  <param value="WARN" name="Threshold" />

  <appender-ref ref="application" />
</logger>
</log4net>
```

This is an excerpt from this article: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18720/Use-Multiple-log-net-Outputs-from-One-Application

Comment: Meer - did this solve your problem?  If so, please mark as answer so others may use in the future.